# Как можно вставить скобки с двух сторон значения через SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql

В колонке есть запись такие как logo,url и тд, как можно вставить скобки чтобы записи были как "logo","url" через SUBSTRING

Comment: Через SUBSTRING - никак. Тем более - скобки, которых в финальном представлении не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Строковая функция SUBSTRING делает совсем другое - возвращает часть подстроки в зависимости от условий. В Вашем случае пригодится CONCAT:

```
    SELECT CONCAT('"','logo','"')\*вместо logo выдаст "logo". Если нужны скобки, то вместо " нужно поставить скобку: '(','logo',')'*\
```